# KSH on Ubuntu on WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, ksh

I just installed the Ubuntu app on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).  It defaults to a bash shell.  I would prefer ksh.  I am quite naive when it comes to using package managers to install software.  I found this link: https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/amd64/ksh/download that says I should use a package manager to install it, but I need more detail help than that.  Can someone help with some detail steps on what I need to do to get ksh installed?
Thanks.

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:        20.04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Use `apt` or `apt-get`: `sudo apt install ksh`

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it?

Comment: Hi,  When I run the apt and apt-get command I get the meesage: Unable to locate package ksh.

Comment: I was able to install it via: downloading the file - http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/ksh/ksh_2020.0.0+really93u+20120801-8_amd64.deb and then running the command: sudo dpkg -i ksh_2020.0.0+really93u+20120801-8_amd64.deb.  I don't think that is how I was supposed to do it.

Comment: I tried adding: deb http://mirrors.kernal.org/ubuntu/ groovy main universe to /etc/apt/sources.list and then running sudo apt-get install ksh, but that didn't work.  If someone knows the right way to do it, I would love to find out.  I got it to work, but I feel like I cheated.

Comment: After adding the universe repository to your sources.list, did you remember to run `sudo apt-get update` before running `sudo apt-get install ksh`?